# Translating my custom theme, always translated version?

Tags: multi-language, translation

I have a custom theme which is in Dutch and now i am trying to translate the theme into english. For this i am using poedit, and converted some theme strings into _e('string-is-here')

I save both en_US.po and en_US.mo into my-theme/languages and add this to functions.php

```
function theme_init(){
    load_theme_textdomain('my-theme', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
}
add_action ('init', 'theme_init');
```

to test it i edit wp-config.php by

```
define('WPLANG', 'en_US');
```

And i thought it was working, but when i changed WP_LANG back to

```
define('WPLANG', '');
```

The translated strings are always shown???

What am i overlooking?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making wrong assumption here. `define('WPLANG', '');` doesn't mean "original locale of the string" or anything like that, it is taken literally as "no locale specified".

And when it's nothing WP proceeds to assume default locale, which is `en_US`. This is why as soon as you add English translations of string they are displayed for this case.

So to test your original Dutch strings properly you need to set `WPLANG` to respective Dutch locale.

Comment: hmm i don't get it. Let me explain in the original theme there are Dutch string like "Gemaakt door", which i replaced  with __('Gemaakt door', 'my-theme'). 
Now with poedit i translate the dutch strong to english "Made by" and saved the file as en_US.mo/en_US.po. Should i saved it asl nl_NL.mo? I am a bit confused as normally it's english translate too another language. regards

Comment: When you have no locale WP thinks it is English. While you had no English translation — original strings where showing. But as soon as you added English translation — those are shown because _locale_ is English. Now your original strings will only show for locales that don't have (or don't need) translation.

Comment: i think i got it now. Do you know how i can set mydomain.com/en/ to set locale WP to use en_US?

Comment: No idea. I tend to use [language switcher plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wcm-user-language-switcher/) for testing.

Answer (score 0):

The `load_theme_textdomain()` function uses `load_textdomain()` internally. And that function offers a nice filter for debugging purposes (aside from altering the language:

```
$plugin_override = apply_filters( 'override_load_textdomain', false, $domain, $mofile );
```

Start debugging with a quick custom plugin and check if your file exists:

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: Check if the themes MO file exists */
add_filter( 'override_load_textdomain', function( $override, $domain, $mofile )
{
    false !== strpos( $mofile, get_template_directory() ) AND var_dump(
        '=== CHECK LANGUAGE AND MO FILES ===',
        $mofile,
        file_exists( $mofile )
        'Current locale: '.get_locale(),
        'Available languages: ',
        get_available_languages(),
    );
    return false;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Note that this will show you **only** parent theme MO files. If you have a child theme in use, you better go with `get_stylesheet_directory()` both in your code as well as in above debug plugin code.

To check your current locale, you can dump `get_locale()`. To see all available languages, dump `get_available_languages()`. Those are the last two dumps in above plugin.